# Failed to follow the Vscode extension tutorial with vscode 1.84.0

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Follow the steps in [your-first-extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension), an error occurs:

```
npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.4 -> 10.2.2
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.2.2
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@10.2.2 to update!
npm notice 
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @types/vscode@^1.84.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/yehaochen/.npm/_logs/2023-11-02T16_42_41_082Z-debug-0.log
Error code
```

I suffered this error in my WSL environment.

Comment: I use npm 6.13 and node 12.14 for extension development, and never had this error, I also never install the `@types/vscode`, I never needed them